# Query: product quantity with customizable variable like color, size

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a report from **stock_reports** table where I want to show quantity of every product with variable like color, size based on created_at means every lot. i have used following Query but i needs some improvement.

```
$stockReport = DB::table('products')
        ->rightjoin('stock_reports','stock_reports.product_id','products.id')
         ->join('sizes','sizes.id','stock_reports.size_id')
         ->join('colors','colors.id','stock_reports.color_id')
        ->select('products.product_name','stock_reports.created_at'
            DB::raw('sum(quantity)'))

        ->groupby('stock_reports.created_at','products.product_name')
        ->orderby('stock_reports.created_at','desc')
        ->get();
```

Output should Like:

```
Name           Quantity    CREATED_AT
product_name1  XL-BLUE-15, L-RED-20 2019-08-12 
product_name2  L-BLUE-15, S-RED-20 2019-08-12
product_name1  M-BLUE-15, L-RED-20 2019-08-13
```

My table Structure:

**products:**

```
 id product_name
```

**stock_reports**

```
 id
 product_id
 size_id
 quantity
 color_id
 sold_price
```

**sizes**

```
  id
  size_name
```

**colors**

```
  id
  color_name
```

Comment: What's the result when you `dd($stockReport)`?

Answer (score 1):

First, create models by terminal or manual

```
php artisan make:model stock_reports
php artisan make:model sizes
php artisan make:model products
php artisan make:model colors
```

Add to file stock_reports.php in a dictionary app

```
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(products::class, 'product_id');
    }
    public function size()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(sizes::class, 'size_id');
    }
    public function color()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(colors::class, 'color_id');
    }
```

Add function reports to products.php

```
    public function reports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(stock_reports::class, 'product_id');
    }
```

Finally in your control use:

```
        $stock_reports=stock_reports::
        with('product')
        ->get()->sortBy('product.product_name')->sortBy('created_at');

        foreach($stock_reports as $report)
        {
            $product_name=$report->product->product_name;
            $size_name=$report->size->size_name;
            $color_name=$report->color->color_name;
            $qty_products=$report->product->reports()->count();

            // use wherever you need to use it

        }
```

Results:

```
Name Quantity CREATED_AT
T-shirt C x-Red-1 2019-09-11 18:55:12
Name Quantity CREATED_AT
T-shirt D xl-Blue-1 2019-09-11 18:55:12
Name Quantity CREATED_AT
T-shirt A xl-Blue-1 2019-09-12 18:55:12
Name Quantity CREATED_AT
T-shirt B x-White-1 2019-09-13 18:55:12
```

Some suggestions:

1. Use [pagination laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) instead of ->get()
2. Use Foreign keys